# Parse HTML and replace Text Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, recursion, translation

I have the following structure tag:

```html
<p class="" id="">
Hi, My name is Vinay Kesharwani &amp; I am the Founder of 
<a class="" href="https://scriptmint.com" rel="noopener ugc nofollow" target="_blank">ScriptMint</a>
. I am a Full Stack Developer working with Laravel, Vue.js &amp; Tailwind CSS.
</p>
```

**I want to translate the text in the whole body, even in nested tags, without breaking the tag structure.**

I wrote a recursive function that takes a tag and then translates the content, as follows:

```py
    def translate_tag(tag):
        if tag.string: 
            trans_text = translator.translate(
                    tag.string
                    )
            tag.string = trans_text
        else: 
            for child in tag:
                if child.name:
                    translate_tag(child)
```

However, the result is not entirely correct; only the contents of the "a" tag are translated:

```html
<p class="" id="">Hi, My name is Vinay Kesharwani &amp; I am the Founder of 
<a class="af np" href="https://scriptmint.com" rel="noopener ugc nofollow" target="_blank">スクリプトミント</a>
. I am a Full Stack Developer working with Laravel, Vue.js &amp; Tailwind CSS.
</p>
```

Please help me to fix my function for the correct translation of nested tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `BeautifulSoup` this is how i would have done it:

```
from bs4 import NavigableString ,BeautifulSoup as bs
h = """
<p class="" id="">
Hi, My name is Vinay Kesharwani &amp; I am the Founder of 
<a class="" href="https://scriptmint.com" rel="noopener ugc nofollow" target="_blank">ScriptMint</a>
. I am a Full Stack Developer working with Laravel, Vue.js &amp; Tailwind CSS.
</p>
"""

soup = bs(h, "html.parser")


def translate_recurse(contents):

    for i in range(len(contents)):
        if type(contents[i])== NavigableString:
            contents[i] =\
NavigableString(translate(contents[i].text)) # translating model you use
        else:
            translate_recurse(contents[i].contents)

translate_recurse(soup.contents)
```

Comment: if i execute print(soup) i will get none, but i need a tag with translated text

Comment: you sure you running the same thing cause it's certainly working on my end.

Comment: what version BeautifulSoup are you using? I completely repeat your code

Comment: i'm using vesion 4.10.0

Comment: Yes, It work for version 4.10.0. Thank you so much